# How to generate a form file from existing code?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In netbeans you can choose to work on "design" or "source". If you don't have a form file, netbeans won't let you see the design and work on that with drag and drop.

I have some existing code with much swing. How can I use the "design" mode in netbeans on that code? To me it seams I can only use the "design" mode if I create a new empty file and work on that.

I can't copy the existing code to new file because netbeans have this autogenerated code that none can edit :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, Netbeans (latest that I try was 6.5) can not generate form file from existen code. So you can only edit it manual, because as you mentored, you can not create new file and copy&paste old code in it.
Also, if you not resrticted with using Netbeanse for edit existen swing components  -you can try IntelliJ IDEA. As I know - it has special tool for working with existen swing windows. Do not remember details, sorry :)
If you don't have IDEA license - you can or:

- try trial for 30 days (if I'm right)
- try beta version.

Hope this helps.